# datetimepicker trigger a javascript function when the 'Done' button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a datetimepicker taken from [here](http://runnable.com/UgCgGBRfEwILAAEt/how-to-create-date-time-picker-using-jquery-ui). This widget let you choose a day from the calendar and set the time. Also there is the button 'Done' which close the widget and sets the date. I need to be able to call a javascript function from my current script, when the button done is pressed. I have tried diffrent solutions but none of them worked:

my_page.html:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
\$(function() { \$('#selectedDateTime').datetimepicker(); });
</script>
...
<input type="text" id="selectedDateTime">
```

I have tried this but it is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#selectedDateTime").datetimepicker({
onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
   my_func();
  }
});
function my_func() {
  alert('my_func triggered');
}
</script>
```

I have managed though to call my function when I change a date or change the time, but I want only to call my function when the button done is pressed. This way I am avoiding calling the function multiple times.

```
<input type="text" id="selectedDateTime" onChange="javascript:my_func"> // this is working, but calls the function all the times, even if the button is not pressed
```

Comment: Are those `backslashes` in `\$(\"#selectedDateTime\")` put by your own intention? Shouldn't it be `$("#selectedDateTime")`?

Comment: Does that plugin have documentation?  Often there is a close event baked into these plugins (if they're made correctly).

Comment: I have removed the backslashes .

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution from [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-done-button-onclick)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function isDonePressed(){
   return ($('#ui-datepicker-div').html().indexOf('ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') > -1);
}

function my_func() {
  if(isDonePressed())
    alert('my_func triggered');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just...

```
$(document).on('click', 'THE-BUTTON-ID/CLASS', function(){
    alert('my_func triggered');
})
```

?